# unable to resolve this No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am getting the below error, When i trying to archive on xcode. In general tab, also shows below one. I have created only provisioning profile for development.

```
No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found.
```

Created provisioning file exist in preferences -> Accounts -> view details.

Comment: check if your distribution certificate contains a private key in keychain. If it doesn't, you need to regenerate your distribution certificate.

Comment: @KKRocks i have not created distribution certificate. Still app is in development mode

Comment: let the XCode create your provisioning profile once yoy have installed the .cert file.

Comment: then how to possible archive without distribution certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using **Automatically manage signing**.

Go to **Target->YourApp->General->Automatically** manage signing.

Check this field and build your project again.

Comment: i cant see Automatically under general tab. I am using xcode Version 7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue also appear when your system time is not set to Automatic.

Please check date time in system preference and set it to automatic and apply. Once done, Clean, Build and archive.